# Undoing a checkin?

Tags: mercurial

I have a project folder like this:

```
project/
   cow/
     a.java
   horse/
     b.java
```

both a.java and b.java were modified. I navigated into horse/, and did:

```
hg ci
```

but for some reason even a.java got checked in, even though I was in a different folder, ugh. Is there a way to undo the checkin? I want to leave the files alone, just basically roll back the checkin. I haven't committed it yet or anything.

For the future, what was the right way to do this checkin, local just to horse/ ?

Thanks

Comment: You have committed it: "ci" is an alias for "commit".

Comment: Paul has your answer but he only touches on the key concept: mercurial changesets are whole-tree changesets and so all commands act on the whole tree by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg checkin foo.java bar.java`

will checkin foo.java and bar.java.

`hg checkin .`

will checkin the local directory.

To rollback, use... `hg rollback`. But it has limitations, ie, it doesn't work with mercurial queues out-of-the-box.